# Adding Google IAP License Key into Unity Games

Tags: unity, android, google-play-services, in-app-purchase

I have added Google Play Services and AdMob successfully into my app. But I want an in-app purchase button that lets you remove the adverts. (I have the button already but not the billing).

Google Developers Console tells me I need to input my app's specific license key into my app. The Android Manifest.xml to be specific. But it's not the clearest instructions. The Unity guide seems very lacking too, and mostly I can only find stuff about Unity IAP.

The Unity guide I did find tells me it makes the Manifest automatically and only tells me that I can write my own complete Manifest and import it over the top of the auto-made one.

I don't really want to do that if possible as I have just finished adding all the other Google stuff via Unity into the Manifest.xml

I'm sure this is a common feature that lots of devs use, so that makes me think there must be some way to do it via Unity.

Answer (score 1):

OK my confusion is solved. Basically I was confused thinking Unity IAP was not the same as Google IAP. In fact, it is, Unity is compatible with Google IAP and many others. So I had to go to Services and enable the IAP to authorize billing on my app.

I also had to retrieve the AndroidManifest.xml from my projects folder (Temp/StagingArea/), edit it in notepad to include the BILLING_PERMISSIONS request, and the save my new Manifest into my project folder (Assets/Plugins/Android), this solved the Billing permissions issue i had